# media queries for iPhone 4, iPhone 4s and iPhone 5

Tags: css, media-queries

```
/* iphone retina portrait, 4inch (iphone 5 and up) */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {
    body {
        background-color: red;   
    }
}

/* retina, iphone, portrait, 3.5inch (iphone 4) */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {
    body {
        background-color: yellow;   
    }
}
```

trying but not working, any ideas, i have to exactly differentiate between iPhone 4, iPhone 4s and iPhone 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the iPhone5, I use pixel ratio 1.5. For the iPhone 4/4S, I use a combination of pixel width and pixel ratio.

```
/* iPhone5+ */ 
@media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
  only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
  only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

/* iPhone 4/4S */
@media 
    only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) 
    and (max-device-width: 480px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
    and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3)
{
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please divide the 4 and 4s separately

Comment: The iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S have the same screen dimensions: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/specs/apple-iphone-4s-specs.html. You would probably have to use Javascript to detect the device and load up different CSS.

Answer (score 6):

Media Queries only for the iPhone 4/4S

**Only iPhone 4/4S (both: landscape and portrait)**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 
480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3)
{
    ...
}
```

**Only iPhone 4/4S (portrait mode)**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) and (orientation:portrait)
{
    ...
}
```

**Only iPhone 4/4S (landscape mode)**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px)  and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) and (orientation:landscape)
{
    ...
}
```

**iPhone 5 only**

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40 / 71) {
    ...
}
```

[More](https://coderwall.com/p/bgf8aa/media-queries-only-for-the-iphone-4-4s-part-ii)

[Also more](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using absolute width in pixels like so:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}
```

Just replace the widths with the phone sizes and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

This following code for sure.I have tried and got it working.Just thought it might help someone save time. Sources:[this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml) and [this](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)

```
/*iPhone 4 and 4S landscape*/
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { 

h1, .h1{
    font-size:26px;
}

.mt-4x{
    margin-top:20px !important;
}
}
```

/*iPhone 4 and 4S portrait*/

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){

h1, .h1{
    font-size:26px;
}

.mt-4x{
    margin-top:20px !important;
}
}
```

Comment: hi @sumedha what I've learned from Michio's answer is that 4 and 4s have the same media queries

Comment: @user2727195 yes this is for 4 and 4s both, Portrait and Landscape screens.